# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Весело(,) как никогда" - что-то не соображу: нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слова «как никогда» выделяются запятыми, вместе с относящимися к ним словами. (Например, было весело, как никогда в жизни)

Если слова «как никогда» тесно связаны по смыслу со сказуемым, то запятые, как правило, не ставятся.

Солнце пекло как никогда. ( Г. Белых, А. Пантелеев, Республика ШКИД). И как никогда было обидно, что его опыты... пошли насмарку.( В. Богомолов, Момент истины). Он служил как никогда. (И. Бунин, Суходол.)

Ваше предложение приведено не полностью, поэтому трудно судить, каким членом предложения является слово весело.

Answer (score 1):

Слова «как никогда» выделяются знаками препинания, обычно запятыми, вместе с относящимися к ним словами. Запятые не ставятся, только если слова «как никогда» связаны по смыслу со сказуемым.

---

В вашем  случае "весело" - сказуемое и "как никогда" связаны со сказуемым по смыслу, так что запятая не ставится.